# Is it possible to compare current user to a SharePoint list/group and switch views if they belong?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, workflow, infopath

So I have a list of managers in my SharePoint site, and I am able to get the current user by using a web service and storing their name into a control. Is it possible to compare this name to everyone in that list/group to check if they are a manager so that the form can switch views to the manager section?

Right now I created a drown down control which pulls in values from the list and sets the default value to the contact. But it can only store and compare one contact. How could I have it compare the current user against everyone in the list?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Sorry I should've specified, this is a 2007 InfoPath form.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, yes, it's possible with this codeplex project: [SPViewPermissionSetting](http://spviewpermission.codeplex.com/)

With this feature you can specify default and available views for a SharePoint group.